# Why does an asp.net user session ending cause a Quartz task in a different app pool to terminate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autofac, quartz

I'm using C# with the Quartz scheduler within an asp.net application. After a user clicks a button on the front end a Quartz task immediately runs in the background, however the task prematurely terminates when the user session ends.

The user session is a different app pool to the one the Quartz session is running in.

Obviously the desired behaviour is for the task to continue even when the user who initiated the task signs out, or their session ends.

Update:
I've added more logging information - what actually appears to cause the task to stop is this:

at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.StopRegisteredObjects(Boolean immediate)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWorkItemCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

The task scheduler class that runs the Quartz tasks was registered in System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment - and when the thread is dispatched it looks like it stops the task scheduler. So this might be closer to where I should be looking - I need to understand why the Thread running the task got dispatched.

---

Initially I thought the problem was do with the Autofac Lifetime scope of the component and my question originally focused on that. I'll leave my Autofac remarks below because it may turn out that this was a factor, I just don't know yet until I solve the problem.

Original Description of Problem:
I'm investigating an issue where the lifetime scope of a  component is incorrectly behaving as if it is a Request Lifetime scope.

Because there are a lot of dependencies I thought if I inspected the Autofac internal code in the debugger it would help me identify what was causing the problem.

However, I'm finding it difficult to understand how lifetime scope is represented internally in Autofac.

Does anyone know how to find the lifetime scope associated with a component within Autofac - in particular if it has request lifetime scope?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of get what you're looking for, but I'm not sure that knowing how lifetime scope works "internally" is quite going to help. Perhaps just getting clear on how scopes work *conceptually* and how parent scopes relate to child scopes will help. [There is a looooot of documentation around this.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html)

If you *actually* want to know how lifetime scope is "represented internally" your best bet is to look through the source. [Start with `ContainerBuilder.Build`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/10c48117bb7c2ef42879409b03c6d981591487e8/src/Autofac/ContainerBuilder.cs#L142) which creates a new [`Container`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/10c48117bb7c2ef42879409b03c6d981591487e8/src/Autofac/Core/Container.cs#L41) (which, itself, has a scope - the "root lifetime scope"). Then look at how [`LifetimeScope`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/10c48117bb7c2ef42879409b03c6d981591487e8/src/Autofac/Core/Lifetime/LifetimeScope.cs#L46) works, resolving components out of registries.

But, like I said, I don't think that will help you as much as the concepts.

Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't tell you where you're going wrong; and there's no error message to indicate any way we can start to help; but what I'm *guessing* is:

- Your app starts up and builds a container.
- The background task starts either based on something resolved from the *container* (probably not good since [that can cause memory leaks for disposable components](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#always-resolve-dependencies-from-nested-lifetimes)) or it starts up from a child scope. **If the child scope the background task starts in is the request scope, that's a problem** - That request scope will be disposed when the given HTTP request is done. If it's not the request scope, fine.
- A request comes in and the controller in your MVC app (or whatever) is generated based on a request lifetime scope. You do some work and, based on something in the controller (possibly a resolved dependency), you hand that to something that hands it to something else that eventually ends up in the background task. **If you hand the background task something that exists because of the request scope, that's bad.** If it's not a simple data object (no state, no `IDisposable`, etc.) then you may get things disposed out from under you when the request ends.

**In general, longer-running background tasks shouldn't try to use data directly from a request.** Instead, you'd be better off pretending the background task is listening on a service bus - create a simple data transfer object (DTO) with no dependencies and hand *that* to the background task to act on. That ensures the request scope won't get tied to anything long-running.

**Here are the things I'd look at** if I was debugging something like this:

- Is the background task or any of its dependencies resolved from a request lifetime scope? Check the actual registrations. If you have `InstancePerRequest` anywhere, that's not good. If you have `InstancePerLifetimeScope` it may or may not be good - `InstancePerLifetimeScope` may mean you get a thing out of a request scope instead of, say, the root container.
- The action that runs when the "session that initiated the task ends" - is that getting some information that came from the request scope? Was it *resolved* somehow? From a database context or anything like that? Could the database context handed to the MVC controller (or whatever) be closing its connection out from underneath the data object associated with the background task work?

[You may also be interested in this Autofac.Analysis package that logs Autofac events to Serilog.](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/03/runtime-analysis-for-autofac/) I can't vouch for it myself, but it could provide some helpful insight.

I hope that helps. If not, at least maybe it can help you figure out where to start looking. Again, I don't think understanding how scope is represented internally to Autofac is going to help you, but maybe the concepts will.

Comment: Thanks I've updated the question now I have more information about the issue. You've given me some good lines of investigation also.

Answer (score 0):

The service app pool was set to on demand with an idle timeout of 20 minutes - that was why it looked like it was the user session that was keeping the task running. Changing the service app pool to always running and setting idle timeout to 0 fixed the problem.